# why 'set' function doesn't work in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, set

when I write in cell

```
set('hello')
```

it raises error 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: the problem isn't Jupyter. are you sure you get this error? set('hello') should yield `{'e', 'h', 'l', 'o'}`

Comment: yes, I get this error

Answer (score -1):

To set an env variable in a jupyter notebook, just use a % magic commands, either %env or %set_env , e.g., %env VAR = VALUE or %env VAR VALUE .

Comment: That is definitely not the goal here and has nothing to do with the question.